# Why does IE open directory links on Windows but Chrome does not?

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, filesystems

The context here is links on a wiki. I want people in the team to open a particular directory to get set up.

I'm using a link similar to the following:

```
<a href="file:///C:/temp">temp</a>
```

This is supported by IE but not Chrome. Is there a particular reason for this?

My question is: **Why does IE open directory links on Windows but Chrome does not?**

EDIT: The reason this question was asked when the other question about links on IE vs Chrome was there was about the 'why' not the 'how to fix'. It is asking a question about *design purpose*.

Comment: Because IE cares less for your security.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Simply untrue. Different browser vendors do different things to protect the end-user. For instance, Chrome allows you to navigate to a dataURI, something we (I work on the Internet Explorer team) have chosen not to allow due to [certain phishing methods](http://klevjers.com/papers/phishing.pdf). We *all* care about your security.

Comment: @hawkeye Which version(s) of Internet Explorer are you using? Also, are you on a local file, or was your document the response of a server?

Comment: @JonathanSampson I'm guessing you work for Microsoft. Saying MS doesn't cares less for security is probably an overstatement, but features like this do make IE less secure for users. P.S. I'm also not a big fan of Chrome, but that's another story.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara If you feel a particular feature puts the end-user at greater risk, please let me know. As stated above, we harden the parts of the browsing experience we feel put the user at higher risk. Sometimes this means we prevent things that Chrome allows, sometime the opposite is true. But the truth is that both vendors take user-security very serious. Please email me directly if you believe this feature can be easily abused: josamp[at]microsoft.

Comment: @JonathanSampson: I can think of a couple of potential attack vectors for this feature, but the feature looks to have been removed in IE11 or earlier, so I guess it's a moot point.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to open file:// links from and http:// or https:// scope, it won't work in Chrome because of their security model... until now! There's now a LocalLinks extension on the Chrome extensions page that will allow you to do it! It's modeled after the LocalLink add-on for FireFox. Enjoy!

Direct link: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida

Comment: It's a nice idea - but that has a bug where you can't open network links.